# If $n^{\alpha}$ is an integer for every $n\in\mathbb N$, is $\alpha$ a nonnegative integer?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, logarithms, exponentiation

Question:

> $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, if $n^{\alpha}$ is an integer for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, then show that $\alpha$ is a nonnegative integer.

I totally don't know how the procedure should go. Besides, I got this problem in the calculus textbook, but I cannot understand why the problem is included in the textbook.

Can you give me some simple key points to this kind of problem? Thanks for your advice.

[**EDIT**] I modified some expressions in order not to have various interpretations.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is in a calculus textbook either, but suppose $\alpha$ is negative. Then $n^\alpha$ is between $0$ and $1$, so not an integer.

Comment: @ElliotG I got that part. But I'm still wondering why $\alpha$ should be nothing but an integer.

Comment: That's clearly false, since we can have $n = 4$, $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$, and we have $4^\frac{1}{2} = 2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes no sense. I mean $8^{1/3}=2$, but $1/3$ is not an integer.

Comment: Think about what a reasonable interpretation should be (not one with easy counterexamples): for $\alpha \in \mathbf R$, if $n^\alpha$ is an integer for every positive integer $n$ then $\alpha$ is a nonnegative integer. You can’t disprove that by making a specific choice of $n$.

Comment: The page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17560/if-2x-and-3x-are-integers-must-x-be-as-well shows how this solved problem is closely related to harder and unsolved problems.